# Howto connect to MySQL with PDO via network device

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, routes, nic

On a system (CentOS 6) with multiple NICs, each connected to an ISP, how can I connect to a MySQL Server on the Internet using one specific NIC on the client machine?

The Client Connector is PHP/PDO.

The default route is set to the desired NIC but PDO doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The only idea that comes to mind is putting the connecting process into a container (docker/rkt) and only bind the correct interface inside of the container. This only makes sense in the following case Architecture!

1. http server and fpm [or PHP in general] are seperated (no apache_mod)
2. the php container has only the 1 NIC available inside

This is arguably not the best solution (at least I don't really like it) but It's a possible workaround.

An other solution is creating/using a proxy that forwards that uses the correct NIC and forwards it so you connect on a "local IP" and the rest in handled via proxy. this should be done via file-socket so the network stack is only from and to the proxy.

The php ticket https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66208 is still open so I wouldn't count on it any time soon.

I hope this is a little help, I'm facing a similar issue. But my setup is very complex and this answer are just my ideas! So pls be kind :)